# EF linq, delete all related OwnerId to Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, `car` and `owner`. `Car`-table uses `OwnerId` as FK.

I must delete cars related to `OwnerId` before I can delete that very `Owner`.

How do I point to every related row from `Car` table and delete them all togheter? As far I get error at the first line:

(It's one to many relation, many cars can have same `OwnerId`)

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id); //this gives me error:   
db.Cars.Remove(car);
db.SaveChanges();

Owner owner = db.Owners.Find(id);
db.Owners.Remove(owner);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Error says: `cannot convert from System.Linq.IQueryable<X.Models.Car> to <X.Models.Car>` . How do I delete all cars related to specific `Id`?

Comment: Look at the return type of the Where expression. Is it the same as Car? Nope. Use var car = db.Cars.Where(x => c.OwnerId == id) instead;

Comment: Don't you have cascaded delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first obtain all cars

```
List<Car> list = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id).ToList();

//Delete all cars
foreach(Car car in list){
    db.Cars.Remove(car);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

Owner owner = db.Owners.Find(id);
db.Owners.Remove(owner);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

the result return list of car.

use following if you only want one result.

```
Car car = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id).FirstOrDefault();//this gives me error:
```

use following for multiple

```
var cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.OwnerId == id).ToList();//this gives me error:
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution for one result as well:)